# Why is Google PDF DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION API much slower than Google JPG DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION API

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-vision

I noticed the Google Vision PDF OCR DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION takes about 15 seconds to detect a single PDF page https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf. 
But if I submit the same PDF page as JPG it takes less than 3seconds to detect texts https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-fulltext

I used the code provided here (C#)https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf#vision-pdf-detection-gcs-csharp

I noticed it takes about 15 seconds for the following line of code to say all text in PDF is detected and saved to gsBucket
`operation.PollUntilCompleted();`

- My GsBucket is "Multi-Regional Storage" US
- I'm also uploading from a US location

I was wondering what else I can do to speed up the process or this is expected?

Comment: How long does it take to convert a PDF to a JPEG?  That might be what it is doing in the background.

Comment: Possible, for me just to do the conversion PDF to JPEG it takes about 1-2 seconds.

Comment: It's possible that it's completing quicker than that - after all, `PollUntilCompleted` does *poll*. You could specify more frequent `PollSettings` just to check that.

Comment: I changed the interval to 1 second, but still no difference, good point tho. 

I'm uploading a PDF then waiting for the text detection result to be saved back on my bucket. The difference between the "last modified" timestamp of the file I uploaded and the file Google saved also shows a difference of ~15 seconds

Comment: It's possible that there's some internal scheduling involved. I'm 99% sure you'd get the same result with other client libraries though - we don't do very much beyond the polling here. You might want to ask on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cloud-vision-discuss...

Comment: They previously only offered offline processing for PDFs.  They've recently released online small batch processing for PDFs, which reduced my latency from ~20 seconds to ~3 seconds. However, I don't see sample code for C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find the answer to your inquiry in this [Google Groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloud-vision-discuss/XZHILmKo8J4). As a summary:

> The offline batch API is not designed to take short running time as
>   the first priority. Instead, it aims to provide scheduling for a large
>   number of multi-page PDF/TIFF files according to quota limits. So
>   instead of sending PDF/TIFF files one by one and wait for each one to
>   succeed, the typical way to use it is to send as many PDF/TIFF files
>   as possible at one time or continuously, track each operation id to
>   get the final result of each PDF/TIFF processing.

The small batch online processing [feature mentioned in the comments](http://%20https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/document-small-batch) doesn't seem to be available in the C# client library yet. Workarounds would be to call the REST API directly or use a client library for a different language.